# Destructuring props dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently building an `AddProductPage` component for my web app. It receives a bunch of `props` from its parent `AddProductContainer` and should divide those `props` among many smaller components that it renders on the page.

Example:

**AddProductPage.js**

```
function AddProductPage(props) {

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Component1
        propsA={props.propsA}
        propsB={props.propsB}
      />
      <Component2
        propsC={props.propsC}
        propsD={props.propsD}
        propsE={props.propsE}
      />
      // And so on...
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I've decided that I will to divide the full `props` object into smaller objects, one for each component, so I can see what my code will render on the page in a cleaner look. Like:

```
function AddProductPage(props) {

  const comp1Props = {
    propsA: props.propsA,
    propsB: props.propsB
  }

  const comp2Props = {
    propsC: props.propsC,
    propsD: props.propsD,
    propsE: props.propsE
  }

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Component1 {...comp1Props}/>    // <--- Easier to see what will render
      <Component2 {...comp2Porps}/>
      // And so on...
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I'm currently thinking if is it possible to dynamically destructure (or some other approach) all `props` into single variables so I can write something like this:

```
function AddProductPage(props) {

  // Some code to destructure all props into single variables

  const comp1Props = {
    propsA,
    propsB
  };

  const comp2Props = {
    propsC,
    propsD,
    propsE
  };

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Component1 {...comp1Props}/>    // <--- Easier to see what will render
      <Component2 {...comp2Porps}/>
      // And so on...
    </React.Fragment>
  );

}
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT**

I think I wasn't being clear enough with my question. But what I meant with dynamically is to destructure everything without knowing the `props` names or how many `props` there are. Is it possible?

Like:

`const {...props} = {...props};   // This is pseudo code`

This way I think my code will be as clean as it can get. Thanks.

Comment: The answers might give you a run for your money, as I don't believe `propsA`, `propsB` etc are the props you want to go for, but they do match your question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Some code to destructure all props into single variables" would be simple destructuring:

```
const { propsA, propsB, propsC, propsD, propsE } = props;
```

Live Example:

```js
const props = {
    propsA: "a",
    propsB: "b",
    propsC: "c",
    propsD: "d",
    propsE: "e"
};

const { propsA, propsB, propsC, propsD, propsE } = props;

const comp1Props = {
    propsA,
    propsB
};

const comp2Props = {
    propsC,
    propsD,
    propsE
};

console.log(comp1Props);
console.log(comp2Props);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

In comments you've clarified:

> what I meant with dynamically is to destructure everything without knowing the props names or how many props there are.

I asked how you would know what to assign to `comp1Props` vs `comp2Props`, and you said:

> I woud still decide that and create those objects manually. But if a pass a new prop to `AddProductPage`, I would like it to be automatically destructured and available to add that into the comp1Props object, for example. Otherwise I would have to remember to destructure it first and then add it to the `comp1Props` object.

So the question is: Can you automatically create constants/variables for all of `props`'s properties in `AddProductPage`, so that they're all available to use in the code creating `comp1Props` and `comp2Props`?

No, you can't do that without using a confusing feature (`with`) that isn't available in strict mode (which is enabled by default in modules). If you could use `with`, you'd just do `with (props) { /*...*/ }` and create your `comp1Props` and `comp2Props` within that block. But you can't use `with` in modern JavaScript.

You're probably best off doing what you're already doing:

```
const comp1Props = {
    propsA: props.propsA,
    propsB: props.propsB
};
```

But if you want to make it shorter, you can give yourself a reusable utility function:

```
function pick(source, ...props) {
    const result = {};
    for (const prop of props) {
        result[prop] = source[prop];
    }
}
```

and then use it in `AddProductPage`:

```
function AddProductPage(props) {
  const comp1Props = pick(props, "propsA", "propsB");
  const comp2Props = pick(props, "propsC", "propsD", "propsE");

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Component1 {...comp1Props}/>
      <Component2 {...comp2Porps}/>
      // And so on...
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

(Some would shoehorn that into a `reduce` call, but there's no need.)

Comment: Thanks! I think I wasn't clear enough with my question. But what I meant with dynamically is to destructure everything without knowing the `props` names or how many `props` there are. Is it possible?

Comment: @cbdev420 - Ah, that's a very different question. How would you know what properties put put in `comp1Props` and which to put in `comp2Props`?

Comment: I woud still decide that and create those objects manually. But if a pass a new `prop` to `AddProductPage`, I would like it to be automatically destructured and available to add that into the `comp1Props` object, for example. Otherwise I would have to remember to destructure it first and then add it to the `comp1Props` object.

Comment: Maybe using `Object.entries()`. I don't know.

Comment: @cbdev420 - I've updated the answer. It's true you could use `Object.entries` (good thought!) and the even-newer `Object.fromEntries` with a `filter` call, but frankly it's ugly and not particularly efficient: `const comp1Props = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(props).filter(([name]) => name === "propA" || name === "propB"));`

Comment: Agreed! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @cbdev420 - It's unfortunate that [this pick syntax proposal](https://github.com/rtm/js-pick-notation) doesn't seem to be finding a TC39 champion. It's what you'd want. :-)

Comment: Not sure since when but now in destructuring is been required to add a default value.

Comment: @CarmineTambascia - Destructuring doesn't require a default value. You just get an error if you try to destructure `undefined` (just like `const { foo } = undefined;`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I phrased it wrongly, I apologize. I indeed got that error because in the parent Component I was refering only a variable instead of the array.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like

```
function AddProductPage(props) {
    //Destructuring props and storing each keys in a sep varaiable  
    const { propsA, propsB, propsC, propsD, propsE } = props;   
    const comp1Props = {
        propsA,
        propsB
    };

    const comp2Props = {
        propsC,
        propsD,
        propsE
    };

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <Component1 {...comp1Props}/> 
            <Component2 {...comp2Porps}/>
            // And so on...
      </React.Fragment>
    );

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I wasn't clear enough with my question. But what I meant with dynamically is to destructure everything without knowing the `props` names or how many `props` there are. Is it possible?

Comment: THen pass all the props directly.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit late to the party, but I would like to make a mention how to make your code readable and thus maintainable. You should separate you code and thus separate your concerns.

Personally I think you are thinking overkill for what you need. For every `Component1`, `Component2`, `Component3` etc. You will be declaring another `const`value, which depending on how many you have will have a performance impact. More importantly, Have you Component and the props being passed in laid out like below (not inline with the component) makes it a lot cleaner.

```
class MyComponentName extends Component {
  getComponentOne = () => {
    const { propsA, propsB } = this.props;

    //Any other logic for component 1 can go here.

    return (
      <Component1
        propsA={propsA}
        propsB={propsB}
      />
    );
  };

  getComponentTwo = () => {
    const { propsC, propsD, propsE} = this.props;

    //Any other logic for component 2 can go here.

    return (
      <Component2
        propsC={propsC}
        propsD={propsD}
        propsE={propsE}
      />
    );
  };

  // Other component method getters

  addProductPage = () => (
    <React.Fragment>
      {this.getComponentOne()}
      {this.getComponentTwo()}
      // Get other component methods
    </React.Fragment>
  );

  render() {
    return(
      // Return whatever you wish here.
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponentName;
```

Two great quotes to think about are from C. Martin in which he stated in his book Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship:

> Even bad code can function. But if code isn’t clean, it can bring a development organization to its knees. Every year, countless hours and significant resources are lost because of poorly written code. But it doesn’t have to be that way.

AND

> “Clean code is code that has been taken care of. Someone has taken the time to keep it simple and orderly. They have paid appropriate attention to details. They have cared.”

Also A note regarding my example above, I am using class components, as I don't know if your component has any other methods/ logic. As if you have other methods in your functional component, on each render those methods would get reinitiated, which again would be a big performance issue.

If you just have a functional component and don't want to separate your code/ has no logic and it only return `JSX` then you could do it the following way.

```
const MyComponentName = ({
  propA,
  propB,
  propC,
  propD,
  propE,
  // Rest of props
}) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Component1
      propsA={propsA}
      propsB={propsB}
    />
    <Component2
      propsC={propsC}
      propsD={propsD}
      propsE={propsE}
    />
    // Rest of you components (If simply returning JSX)
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Hope the above is of some help to you.

Comment: My current design scheme for the `AddProduct` page (every page is like this) on my app is like this: I have a `AddProductContainer` that handles API calls and holds all the `state` needed for that specific page. That component renders a `AddProductPage` with a whole bunch of props. The `AddProductPage` is responsible for rendering the page's UI components, each one with its respective props.

Comment: So I'm conditionally rendering 8 components, depending on `loading` and `error` status, for example. So the `return` of `AddProductPage` was getting too crowded with conditions and components with 4 or 5 `props` each. It was hard to reason what was being rendered on each `state` condition. That's when I started to look for another place to "organize" the `props` for each component. And call each one with a single `prop` object.

Comment: If I destructure them all on the component function declaration as you did on your last example, if I create a new `prop` in my `ContainerComponent` I would have to remember to add it in two places in my `PageComponent` instead of only one. That's why I was looking for a way to destructure them all dynamically. Thank you so much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
function AddProductPage({propsA, propsB, propsC, propsD, propsE}) {
```

Or

```
const {propsA, propsB, propsC, propsD, propsE} = props
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I wasn't clear enough with my question. But what I meant with dynamically is to destructure everything without knowing the props names or how many props there are. Is it possible?